# Hyperapp with list and clock, want to refresh list every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, hyperapp

I've got the following code https://pastebin.com/gp4VerFN/
`subscriptions:`
which fetches a list of names etc from a URL.

It also has a timer, which updates a span with the current time every second.
I'd now like to refresh the list every X seconds but I'm not able to get it to work. Could anyone please explain how its done?

TIA
ps. As this is meant to be used offline I've downloaded the hyperapp & time code.

I've tried a number of things and even asked chatgpt but no luck.